# Change modification date to filename

Tags: linux, bash, touch

I've got a number of files of which I want to change the modification date in linux. The modification date is saved in the filename.

So I've got files, whose name is for example "IMG_20180101_010101.jpg", but the modification date is today. I want to change the modification date to 2018-01-01 01:01:01, as in the filename. 
I've tried with find and touch:

```
find . -iname 'IMG*' -print | while read filename; do touch -t {filename:7:8} "$filename"; done
```

When I do this I always get an error ("invalid date format: {filename:7:8}).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the file timestamp according to the filename, you can try this:

```
find -type f -name "IMG_*" -exec bash -c 'touch -t $(sed "s/.*IMG_\([0-9]\{8\}\)_\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\).jpg$/\1\2.\3/" <<< "$1") "$1"' _ {} \;
```

As mentionned in the `touch` man page, the option `-t` expects a format `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`. That's the purpose of the `sed` command.

Comment: Works like a treat. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood good, you would like to write the file names in your own format. What about this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

suffix=".jpg"

for file in "IMG*"; do # Careful, the loop will break on whitespace
    fileDate=$(echo $file| cut -d'_' -f 2)
    year=${fileDate:0:4}
    month=${fileDate:4:2}
    day=${fileDate:6:2}

    fileHour=$(echo $file| cut -d'_' -f 3 | sed -e s/$suffix//)
    hour=${fileHour:0:2}
    min=${fileHour:2:2}
    secs=${fileHour:4:2}
    newName="$year-$month-$day $hour:$min:$secs$suffix"
    mv $file "$newName"
done
```